# c++ Check end of cin with istream::peek in a loop

Tags: c++

I want to read an istream and separate it into tokens checking the next character in the sequence using `istream::peek`. However, i can't reach the way to end the loop without inserting a certain character in the end of the input.

Is there any way to check if the next character is the end of the input? I have tried while(c != is.eof()) but it doesn't work.

```
void calculator(istream& is){
  //Some structures

  char c = '0';  

  while (c != '.'){    
    c = is.peek();
    switch (c){
           //Some operations with is
           //is.ignore(1);
           //is >> variable;
    }
  }

int main (void){
   calculator (cin);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From `std::istream::peek()`'s [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) it says:

> ### Return value
>
> If `good() == true`, returns the next character as obtained by `rdbuf()->sgetc()`
>   Otherwise, returns `Traits::eof()`.

So you should check the return value against `Traits::eof()`:

```
int c = 0; // Note peek() returns `int_type` actually not char
while (c != '.'){    
    c = is.peek();
    if(c == std::char_traits::eof())
    {
        break;
    }
    switch (c){
           //Some operations with is
           //is.ignore(1);
           //is >> variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though i couldn't get it to work. I got the missing template argument error so i added <char> after char_traits.  However, after compiling I get the same result, if no point is inserted at the end of input the loop won't exit.